# Python dictionaries duplicate removal logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to understand the Python logic behind removal of duplicates in a dictionary. It seems that the last element in line is always kept. Is that the case?

`print({True: 5, True: 10})` gives `{True: 10}`.

Why not `{True: 5}`?